# Template parameter pack and function pointer with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Given this template function:

```
template<typename Ret, typename Arg, Ret Func(Arg)> void foo() {
  // do something with Ret and Arg
}
```

And this ordinary function:

```
int bar(float a) { return 0; }
```

It is possible to compile the following statement:

```
foo<int, float, &bar>;
```

Now I change the template parameters to be variadic in order to support pointers to functions with a variable number of arguments:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args, Ret Func(Args...)> void foo() {
  // do something with Ret and Args
}
```

The above statement won't compile anymore. I tested it with MinGW (C++17) and received the error `error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: A parameter pack will try to consume all remaining arguments, no matter what. Just do `template <auto Func>`.

Comment: I need the types ``Ret`` and ``Arg`` (``Args...``, respectively) in the body of the template function. This wouldn't work with your solution, would it?

Comment: **You have a typo.** `typename Args...` should be `typename... Args`.

Comment: This is what specializations are for. Do you know what template specializations are, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: Fixed the typo, sorry.

Comment: Regarding specializations: I have a rough idea, but I'm not sure how I could use them here.

Comment: @csk Just remove the third non type template parameter and instead make it a function parameter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77315821/12002570).

Comment: "I need the types Ret and Arg (Args..., respectively) in the body of the template function." you can get them via traits once you have the function pointer passed to the function

Answer (score 3):

Changing to `template <auto Func>` would solve your issue:

To extract `Ret(Ts...)`, you might create type traits, or call a function which can deduce them:

```
template <auto Func> void foo() {
    return []<typename Ret, typename... Ts>(std::type_identity<Ret(Ts...)>){
        // do something with Ret and Arg
        // ...
    }(std::type_identity<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(Func)>>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5qY4E7WeP)

Answer (score 1):

In ended up with the following solution making use of `auto` and explicitly stating the return and arguments types (just with a different order):

```
template<auto Func, typename Ret, typename... Args> void foo() {
  // do something with Func, Ret and Args
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve is this remove the third nontype template parameter and instead take make it as a function parameter as shown below:

```
//-------------------------------------v----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--->moved the template parameter to function parameter
template<typename Ret, typename... Args> void foo(Ret Func(Args...)) 
{
 
}

int bar(float a) { return 0; } 

int main()
{
//------------------vvvv----->pass &bar as function argument instead of template argument
    foo<int, float>(&bar);  //works now

    foo(&bar);     //THIS WORKS TOO  
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hYhrGMor8)

Comment: This would change the signature of the instantiated function. This is not possible in my case, I'm afraid, because I need to further process pointers to every instantiated function (regardless of the function that goes into the template), and all these pointers must have the same type.

Comment: @csk This vital information was not provided in the original question. So afaik this answers your original question. For follow up question/requirements, kindly ask a new separate question. You can't/shouldn't just add requirements to your question after there are already answer(s) to the question.